# JsonTemplateLayout: Can log level be converted to lower case?

Tags: java, log4j2

According to [JsonTemplateLayout Document](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html), I have confirmed that printing the log level can be done as follows.

```json
{
  "level": {
    "$resolver": "level",
    "field": "name"
  }
}
```

When the schema is set in the above manner, the log level is output in uppercase letters such as `{"level":"DEBUG"}`. I would like to change this to lower case. However, there was no luck as a result of proceeding as follows.

```json
{
  "level": "${lower:${level.name}}"
}

=> {"level":"${level.name}"
```

```json
{
  "level": "${lower:${level:name}}"
}

=> {"level":"${level:name}"
```

Project Environment:

- Spring Boot 2.4.3
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2
- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-layout-template-json:2.14.1

Is there a way to print the log level in lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonTemplateLayout` author speaking here. You can fallback to `PatternLayout` as follows:

```json
{
  "level": {
    "$resolver": "pattern",
    "pattern": "%level{lowerCase=true}"
  }
}
```

This said, I am curious about your use case. Why do you want to lowercase the level? (For the records, created [LOG4J2-3051](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3051) to address this issue. Though the use case still puzzles me.)

Comment: That's because my organization's logging convention requires that log levels be printed in lowercase. Thanks for letting me know anyway!

Comment: Okay, interesting. I have created [LOG4J2-3052](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3052) to address this shortcoming.